# Replace a throw formatexception with a messagebox

Tags: c#

I have this code that works, however, if a user enter an invalid character, I would like a message box to appear instead of throwing the formatexception...

Claude

I tried changing the formatexception with a message box without success.
I was seeing the messagebox but the code continue

```cs
public bool ValiderNomUtil(string nomUtil)
{
    nomUtil = UsernameTB.Text;
    if (nomUtil == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException("Le champ nomUtil ne peut être null. The nomUtil field cannot be null.");

    if (Regex.IsMatch(nomUtil, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9 @:!#$%&'()*+,-.=?_|~ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ]{1,64}$")) // par exemple : XXX
        return true;
    else
        throw new FormatException("Le format de données du champ nomUtil doit être une suite de 1 à 64 caractères respectant les normes ASCII. The data format for the field nomUtil must be a string of 1 to 64 characters according to ASCII standards.");
}
```

Comment: You say the code continues after showing the message box. What did you want it to do instead?

Comment: The problem is that even if I enter MessageBox.show(""); the message box is not showing, this comments is for Alexander, if you look at the code I posted, do you see any messagebox, no, so using the code above, how can I show a messagebox instead of the throw new FormatException...

Comment: Please provide the exact code you have tried out. This will help to answer your question. The issue could be there or outside the method as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this code snipped?

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(nomUtil, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9 @:!#$%&'()*+,-.=?_|~ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ]{1,64}$")) // par exemple : XXX
    return true;
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Le format de données du champ nomUtil doit être une suite de 1 à 64 caractères respectant les normes ASCII. The data format for the field nomUtil must be a string of 1 to 64 characters according to ASCII standards.");
    return false;
}
```

If this is similar to the code you have tried so please check the calling code of ValiderNomUtil() for the issue or provide more details.